# Validation of number input with max input and maximum of 2 decimal places doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a number input field in a form. And I've set the maximum number of decimal places to be `2` and the maximum value to be `99999999999999`

If I try to submit a value of `99999999999999999` it detects it has too big and doesn't allow it.
If I try to submit `99.123` it detects it has too many decimal places and doesn't allow it.

But if I try to submit `99999999999996.123` it doesn't detect that it has too many decimal places.

How can I fix this?

```js
var app = angular.module('Appp', []);

app.controller('metadataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.vm = { myItems : {} }

    $scope.item = {type: "a", value: 99999999999998};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="Appp" name="myForm" ng-controller="metadataCtrl">

  <input type="number"
         step="0.01"
         max="99999999999999"
         min="0"
         step-message="{name} can only have a maximum of 2 decimal places"
         ng-model="item.value"/>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

 </form>
```

Comment: Just execute `console.log(99999999999996.123)`, and you'll understand the reason. A number is just 64 bits. You can't store the infinity of real numbers in just 64 bits. The largest the number is, the least precise it becomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about decimal places, your input `99999999999996.123` is still lower than `99999999999999`; `max` is not related  to decimal places but the number it self, if you want to validate decimal places you should create a directive validator you self. Furthermore, the `step` attribute doesn't limit decimal places but only specify that you have to use values that increments at the specified rate, that is, it will accept only values at multiples of the step.

> Ref.: [MDN web docs -`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Perhaps, you could use `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"` that validates 2 decimal places. However, you will get problems using such a large number, because javascript number is defined by 64 bits so as the number grows you lose precision an it's hard to treat the input value as a number it self; for example: `9999999999999999` is evaluated to `10000000000000000`.

The following example uses ng-pattern to validate decimal places, however, it doesn't prevent javascript Number pit falls.

```js
var app = angular.module('Appp', []);

app.controller('metadataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.vm = {
    myItems: {}
  }

  $scope.item = {
    type: "a",
    value: 9999999999999.99
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="Appp" name="myForm" ng-controller="metadataCtrl">

  <input type="number"
         step="0.01"
         max="99999999999999"
         min="0"
         name="myField"
          ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"
         ng-model="item.value"/>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br>
  {{ myForm.myField.$error }}
  <br>
  <span ng-if="myForm.myField.$error.pattern">myField can only have a maximum of 2 decimal places</span>
</form>
```

Comment: It does have an effect on validation. Type 0.12 in the following demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xih8PR6D5uU0W2xgWxNU?p=preview

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: is there a way to detect this kind of problem? for now i just made the supported max to have less a digit

Comment: @RagnaRock It's a javascript number defect, the number is composed by thee parts: `number`, `exponent` and `signal`. So to make the number fit the parts, it's rounded, and you lose precision when it does that, again, it's a defect. A typical example is `0.2 + 0.1` which javascript evaluates to `0.30000000000000004`. People usually multiply each number by ten or hundred depending on the precision and is fine, but there's no much how to deal with it, setting a more realistic max will do, because you are not doing operations on it so you'll be fine.

Comment: Just make sure javascript evaluates the number to the number itself not a rounded version of that you can test using `console.log(999999999999)`;